# Schreiber/Sati Hypothesis H and emergence of spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, ontology

Good day,
I am a lay person in this field So i am very sorry if my question Is dumb.

I am wondering whether the [Hypothesis H](https://ncatlab.org/schreiber/show/Hypothesis+H) formulated by Schreiber and Sati stating that C-field is charge quantized in J-twisted Cohomotopy theory doesnt assume already existing spacetime manifold And a C-field which would together constitute the ontology of this theory?

Doesnt this go against ideas of Nima Hamed And others who would like to create a deeper mathematical structure from which both spacetime And Quantum fields emerge?

Comment: Links to abstract pages?

Comment: May I ask why the downvote?

Comment: It's an excellent question, and for those who don't like the reference to "ontology", just think of it as asking about the relationship between Hypothesis H and what Arkani-Hamed et al are doing.

Answer (score 1):

The original amplituhedron represents N=4 super-Yang-Mills, which is holographically dual to Type IIB string theory; and M-theory is Type IIA string theory at strong coupling; and IIA and IIB are T-dual. So there ought to be some compatibility. Maybe you could get there via ABJM theory, which is dual to M2 branes but which also has its own amplituhedron.